# how to remove line break in twig template containing a for loop and an include?

Tags: twig

I would like to remove a line break between multiple html tags (`<a>`) from a twig template which contains a for loop and an `include` of another twig template.

```
{% for child in field.value %}
    {% include '@EasyAdmin/crud/field/association_link.html.twig' with {
        field: {
            value: child,},
    } %}
    {%- if loop.index < field.value|length -%}
        ,
    {%- endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And the twig templated included :

```
{% set url = ea_url()
    .setController('App\\Controller\\Admin\\' ~ get_class(field.value)|split('\\')|last ~ 'CrudController')
    .setEntityId(field.value.id)
    .setAction('edit') %}
{% if url -%}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ field.value|markdown }}</a>
{%- else -%}
    {{ field.value|markdown }}
{%- endif -%}
```

It renders such a result :

```
<a href=url2>name1<a/>

,
<a href=url2>name2<a/>
```

How to get this result instead ?

```
<a href=url2>name1<a/>,
<a href=url2>name2<a/>
```

[2nd row, 6th field : a break line before and after the comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwNbl.png)

Comment: How does this affect the output of your site?

Comment: I edited the post with a screenshot from the web site, you can have a look, thanks!

Comment: That "whitespace" should not affect the actual output - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/orkLpte6/). Please verify that your CSS is not causing the problem, e.g. `a { display: block; }`

Comment: The problem comes from the <a> that contain a <p>, such as :
`<a href="url"><p></a>
,
<a href="url"><p></a>`
The `<p>` renders the break line...

Comment: `twig` itself is not responsible for that (extra) `<p>`-tag in any way. You will need to find out where that `<p>`-tag comes from.

Comment: May `{{ field.value|markdown }}` create a `<p>` tag ?

Comment: I replaced `{{ field.value|markdown }}` by `{{ field.value|raw }}` and completed the condition :
`{%- if loop.index < field.value|length -%}
        {{ ",\n"|nl2br }}
  {%- endif %}`